# How Sri Raghavendra Swami's Vrindabana was built?

Tags: temple, vaishnavism

All, I am a devotee of Guru Raghavendra Swami, as most of you're aware of his moola brindavana is located in Mantralayam, Andhra Pradesh. My query is how the brindavana is built up actually?

Like first Guru did entered the samadhi and on top of the samadhi did they build brindavana or have they followed any other procedure? Also those days we didn't had advanced engineering technologies, if this is the case how can they perfectly carve the stone of moola brindavana?

Can anyone help me? Sorry if it's a silly question, I have seen in movies but different movies shows entering of brindavana in different ways.

Comment: Guru entered samadhi and the brindavana was constructed around him AFAIK.

Comment: This is detailed in the book Kaliyugada Kalpataru. However only the first half of the book is available online https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23964/is-the-kaliyugada-kalpataru-available-online.

Comment: @BhargavRao The main part of my question itself is missing in that book :) Any idea where can I get physical copy or full edition of the book?

Comment: Yep, that's why I did not answer. :-). I did not find the book anywhere in Bangalore, so I bought the book when I went on a trip to Mantralaya. This was 5 years back, though. I think now, you can buy it in Vedanta Book House in Chamarajapet. (assuming that your location  is B'lore, which is on your profile).

Comment: Great thanks!! I would try to buy it from there :)