# Is the Kaliyugada Kalpataru available online?

Tags: resource, dvaita

The book Kaliyugada Kalpataru, written by Raja Gururajacharya, (who was the son from the poorvashrama of Sri Raghavendra Swami), is a complete biography of Sri Raghavandra Swami.

While writing my answer for a question asking about the previous incarnations of Sri Raghavendra Swami, I searched online, but I was not able to find it.

Is there an online copy of the book available?

Comment: If i google search with "kaliyugada kalpataru" it returns a suggestion- "Did you mean: kaliyuga kalpataru ?" and if i accept, it shows the results found in the given answer.

Comment: @Rickross I just got results pointing to some other music album  https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2cKC.png. Perhaps an Indian IP would have helped, or perhaps I should have used google.co.in instead. I'll take care next time, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is available on archive.org in Kannada Language in multiple links.

#### 1.[Kaliyuga Kalpataru](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.382068)

#### 2. [ಕಲಿಯುಗ ಕಲ್ಪತರು](https://archive.org/stream/Kaliyuga-Kalpataru-1994/Kaliyuga-Kalpataru#page/n3/mode/2up)

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I was searching for Kaliyuga*da* Kalpataru, which was not returning any results. Thanks.